Creating a YoY, QoQ, MoM Growth/Degrowth from a Table with Multiple Category
I want to display the Year-on-Year (YoY), Quarter-on-Quarter (QoQ), etc. as a static value in Power BI dashboard. To display the same, I can simply do:
Total Sales = SUM(sales['quantity'])                   # first measure
MTD = TOTALMTD([Total Sales], DATESMTD(sales['date'])) # second measure

However, the table has multiple categories clubbed together like:



date
category
quantity
amount




2010-01-01
A
100
9


2010-01-01
B
601
6


2010-01-01
C
501
3


2010-01-02
A
200
9


2010-01-02
B
600
6


2010-01-02
C
500
3



I've added category in a slicer for selection, but the table is not filtered.
How to create a dynamic measure to show the YoY, QoQ, etc. based on the selected category?
Also, I have a large number of categories and creating a filter for each is practically not possible. Either a DAX Query, or a working SQL that can be imported into PowerBI from the table works for me.
